# Error en Laravel cuando intento migrar la base datos con herencia

Tags: laravel, artisan

Estoy haciendo un proyecto de php en Laravel y tengo una base de datos con herencia. Al hacer php artisan migrate me sale este error

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError  : Too few
>   arguments to function CreatePersonaTable::up(), 0 passed in
>   /home/vagrant/Code/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Migrations/Migrator.php
>   on line 387 and exactly 1 expected

Mi tabla padre es esta:

```
class CreatePersonaTable extends Migration
{
public function up(string $tablename)
    {
        Schema::create($tablename, function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string("nombre");
            $table->string("dni");
            $table->integer("telefono");
            $table->string("apellidos");
            $table->integer("edad");
            $table->string("direccion");
            $table->string("foto");
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('persona');
    }
}
```

Y la tabla hijo esta:

```
class CreateOperadorTable extends CreatePersonaTable
{
    public function up(string $tablename)
    {
        parent::up("operador");
        Schema::create('operador', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('operador');
    }
}
```

No entiendo como lo tengo que poner para que se pueda migrar correctamente la base de datos.

Muchas gracias!